# How do I get a date in UK local time using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using the **unix timestamp** to show when a message was posted in my project but when I came to displaying the exact time of the post I realized it was about 12 hours behind.

I'm in the UK and my server is in the US (might be the problem).

Is there a simple way of converting the unix timestamp into a readable British time?

```
$timestamp = time();
print date("F jS, Y", strtotime($timestamp));
```

Any help would be great,
Thanks!

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your question titles. You've done it with almost all of your questions.

Comment: Can you show some code? Where are the dates coming from?

Comment: Sorry Tom, didn't realize that was a problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Use my solution that is very clear and easy.    
         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176502/php-get-uk-local-time-from-server-in-different-time-zone/70781686#70781686

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your script, write:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Or [if your PHP is >= 5.2.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php):

```
date_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: this is in complete solution

Answer (score 2):

Just call [`date_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php) with the appropriate parameter for the UK at the start of your script *when displaying the dates* (not when *recording* them; I 'm not sure, but it might result in the "wrong" timestamps being recorded).

**Edit:** The timezone you want is `'Europe/London'`.

Comment: I hope not. Otherwise any script running outside of GMT is in big trouble.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I don't quite get your meaning. I was thinking that the behavior would be dependent on the system clock going with UTC time vs. the local time. In the second case only PHP would need to convert from local to UTC to get a timestamp; therefore setting the "wrong" local timezone would result in a wrong TS. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Depends what he's doing, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

try [date-default-timezone-set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); to set the time zone to London's time. Not sure if it works with summer/winter time.

Answer (score 0):

the simplies way is to substruct gmt offset. e.g:

```
echo(date('Y-m-d h:i'), $myvalue - 60 * 60 * $nhours));
```

where $nhours - time defference in hours.

Comment: Sure, if you want to write this mess every single time you want to work with a date.

Comment: your solution does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```