# Convert a mySQL date to a British time format in Laravel 5.2 using Carbon?

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

My datetimepicker is incorrectly showing a date as 20th May 2026, because it was stored in MySQL as 2016-05-26. 
At the moment I think this is what I should do:

```
$startDate = new Carbon ('d/m/Y H:i:s', $dateFromDB->startdate);
```

Comment: you can do this by using my solution. check the link and you can get results as you are looking.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176502/php-get-uk-local-time-from-server-in-different-time-zone/70781686#70781686

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Converting twice, why?**

One issue I have with your question is that you are getting the date from the DB as `Y-m-d`, then converting it to `d/m/Y H:i:s` then your date-picker is showing it as `jS F Y`, couldn't you cut out one conversion rather than converting it twice? Something to consider.

**New'ing up a Carbon Instance**

If you're getting a date from the DB as `Y-m-d` then you can directly pass it into the Carbon instance you are new'ing up:

```
$startDate = new Carbon($dateFromDB->startdate);
```

See the docs: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Then you can use the `format()` method to output the desired date format:

```
$startDate->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // 26/05/2016 09:30:05

$startDate->format('jS F Y'); // 26th May 2016
```

**Date Mutators in Eloquent**

Another approach you may consider if you are using eloquent to get the date you are transforming is to automatically cast the date to a Carbon instance by adding it to the `$dates` attribute in your model.

For example if your date is `start_date` in your model, you would do this:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $dates = ['start_date'];
}
```

Then you can access it directly in your code as a Carbon instance:

```
MyModel::first()->start_date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

**Using PHP Only**

You can also use plain old PHP like this to get the date format you require:

```
$date = '2016-05-26 09:30:05';

$startDate = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($date)); // 26/05/2016 09:30:05

$startDate = date('jS F Y', strtotime($date)); // 26th May 2016
```

Comment: Excellent! I am familiar with the PHP date() function and the newer DATETIME(). But I wanted to use a bit of Carbon since my application is in Laravel and it would be nice to have the security features that it provides. Thanks a million, this really helped!

Comment: @omrakhur You are more than welcome, so glad I could help out! There's a lot of functionality built into Carbon so consider diving into the docs and the source code to get more out of it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateFromDatabase = "2016-05-20";

$dt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateFromDatabase);

// Where js F Y results in 20th May 2016
echo $dt->format('jS F Y');
```